# Как запустить проект с GitHub?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно имплементировать в свой проект `NumberPicker`, я нашел на Github'e пример. [Вот он](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker), но не могу его открыть.

Обычно я делаю это двумя способами:

1. Просто делаю клон и открываю с студии.
2. Если первый способ не открывает проект, то я делаю импорт file - new - import project нажимаю далее - далее и все открывается.

Но в этот раз он все равно не открывается.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Как открыть проект?

Вот так выглядит проект после импорта, здесь нет кнопки запуска проекта...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Градл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно значит `все равно не открывается`? Клещами из вас тянуть ошибки, скриншоты...?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, у вас, возможно, не указаны пути к папкам, где лежит сам код, вот и студия не знает что запускать. Вы бы хоть на скрине раскрыли папки бы, что ли...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну... Может надо ещё и градл файлы добавить...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, но по ссылке с гита с которой я качал проект, там нет гдадл файлов... Я так понимаю их самому нужно собрать? Я раньше делал Build - Rebuild project, но в этом проекте есть Build но нет Rebuild project... А как можно еще собрать градл файлы?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну, по идее вам надо самому их создать и в них написать нужное по аналогии с работающими проектами.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Студия по умолчанию создает перечень файлов которые как я понимаю относятся к градл(скрин добавил) их все нужно переписать под этот проект? или вы не сталкивались с таким?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, они у вас на скрине, под папками с кодом не отображаются - видимо да, их надо отредактировать. Однажды у меня долго что-то не собиралось и помогла перезагрузка) Студия, кстати, на скрине вам и говорит, что что-то с градлом надо сделать.

Answer (score 3):

Проект примера сделан в Eclipse, поэтому и не получится так просто открыть в Android Studio.

В [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/sdk/installing/migrate.html) описано как мигрировать с Eclipse в Android Studio

Comment: Я сделал как было показано в документации, но у меня все равно осталась проблема. Я добавил скриншот. Про что я забыл?

Comment: Как вы считаете в чес может быть проболема?